# Upgrade from 16.04.2 to 18.04 fails to boot

Tags: 16.04, nvidia, 18.04, macbook, nouveau

I've been trying to install the latest and greatest 18.04 on my Apple MacBook 7.1. I meet the system requirements but couldn't seem to get the live USB to boot correctly, it would just flash the screen on and off. So I installed 16.04.2 perfectly fine and then tried to upgrade to the latest LTS through 16.04.2. Now it won't boot and nouveau fails to idle (probably the Nvidia 320M giving me trouble).

Anyway, is there any way to recover the past 16.04.2 without a fresh install? And any good place to check out if and when this bug with graphics cards is resolved (seems to be a common issue).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid you will not be able to easily go back to 16.04 without a fresh install.

For your information, I have a Macbook Pro 7.1 and I experienced a very similar problem which seems to be linked with the kernel 4.15. This kernel doesn't support well the nouveau driver for Nvidia graphic card. Maybe that is what stucked your laptop. If your lucky, you have another kernel installed and then you can boot with this kernel selectionning it in the GRUB menu at startup. I'm not sure however that your system will work fine with this older kernel but you can make a try.

If you want something newest than 16.04 : my Macbook Pro 7.1 is working fine with Ubuntu 17.10 and kernel 4.13.

Comment: Ah, thank you! I currently decided to to a complete reinstall and stuck with 16.04 for the moment. I may try to upgrade it using the kernel you suggested in the near future. Good to know that it has been a common issue and that you have found a solution.

Answer (score 0):

I've got a similar problem. After upgrading my server from 16.04 LTS to 18.04 LTS it won't boot and got stuck in the initramfs shell. It said it couldn't find the  initrd.img.

I booted into an **recovery kernel** (using the grub menu) and rerun

```
sudo grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg
```

But not before making a backup copy of the `grub.cfg` file there.
After a reboot it booted clean into 18.04.1 LTS with kernel 4.15.0-32-generic as

```
uname -a
```

showed me properly.

Cheers